# Max Salary with a single GroupBy without Joins

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Schema for EMPLOYEE

```
(ID, EMPLOYEENAME, SALARY, ORGANIZATIONID)
```

Query to Solve: Find employee Names in each organization with Maximum Salary **without a Join**.

```
SELECT E.* 
FROM EMPLOYEE E,
 (SELECT EMP.ORGANIZATIONID, MAX(EMP.SALARY)
 FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
 GROUP BY EMP.ORGANIZATIONID) MAXSALARY
WHERE MAXSALARY.SALARY =E.SALARY
AND E.ORGANIZATIONID=EMP.ORGANIZATIONID ;
```

Is there a way to avoid the join? I am using Spark SQL API and joins cause an extra shuffle operation which is expensive. Is there a way to get the employee name while getting the max salary?

> Assume you have a single employee in each organization having the max salary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PARTITION BY` with Spark SQL as shown below (Although it will require a subquery)

```
SELECT E.* 
FROM 
 (SELECT EMP.EMPLOYEENAME, EMP.ORGANIZATIONID, EMP.SALARY,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ORGANIZATIONID ORDER BY SALARY DESC) as rank
  FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
 ) AS E
WHERE E.rank=1
```

Comment: you had better using `dense_rank` instead of `row_number` for probability of ties occuring +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.ORGANIZATIONID, P.EMPLOYEENAME
FROM EMPLOYEE P
WHERE P.SALARY = (SELECT MAX(E.SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE E WHERE P.ORGANIZATIONID = E.ORGANIZATIONID)
GROUP BY P.ORGANIZATIONID, P.EMPLOYEENAME
```

Comment: Why do you have a `group by`?

Comment: I use the group by to colapse results for each organization. The question needs answers that do not use a join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEENAME FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE SALARY IN (SELECT MAX(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY ORGANIZATIONID)
```

Comment: This answer is incorrecct.

Comment: Why @GordonLinoff? Tell me more.

Comment: . . Because it can return employees whose salary matches the maximum of a salary in *another organization*.